# How much 10% hypochlorite should I use?

Tags: water

The chlorine injection system for my well water currently requires 192 oz. of 6% household bleach for 30 gallons of solution.  How many ounces of 10% pool bleach would be required to achieve the same dilution rate?

Comment: Hi Tony; this seems like more of a [chemistry](https://site.stackexchange.com/)  question (e.g. how to calculate dilution) than a home improvement question.

Answer (score 0):

It's a ratio, 6 vs 10, 192 vs ?. 6/10 of 192 = 115. For a quick check, you'd expect 12%, double 6% to take 1/2 as much which is 96

Answer (score 0):

192oz * 0.06 = 11.52oz of chorine

At 10%, you'll need 115.2oz (11.52oz * (100/10))